# how to check if personID is in my_customers (see my example)

Tags: c++

In C++, the interface for this file says

```
*If no soup left returns OUT_OF_SOUP
* If personID not found in my_customers AND numbBowlsSoupLeft>0 then give this person a bowl of soup (return BOWL_OF_SOUP) 
* and record it by creating new customer struct using personID, numbBowlsSoup=1 and adding this struct to my_customers, be sure to decrement numbBowlsSoupLeft.
```

for my implementation, I'm trying to put

```
int Soupline::getSoup(int personID) {
     if (numBowlsSoupLeft == 0) {
          return OUT_OF_SOUP;
     }
     if (!(personID : my_customers) && numbBowlsSoupLeft > 0) {
          }
```

But that second if statement is giving me syntax errros, I just want to know how to check to see if the personID is IN my_customers?

my_customers was created in the soupline interface using:

```
std::vector<customer> my_customers; // keeps track of customers
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but at the second `if` statement, the code has already checked for no soup, so the second `if` statement doesn't have to check it again.

Comment: @PeteBecker okay i changed it

Comment: Okay; so, what do you know about `std::vector` that might be useful here?

Comment: literally nothing i don't understand C++

Comment: Currently there is no simple and slick "Is X in a `vector`?" syntax. You'll have to call a [`find` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 0):

First you want to use find() to search a vector.
Second, please handle the case if numbBowlsSoupLeft < 0, because that can be a huge source of problem.
Third, your syntax error is the (personID : my_customers), the : is for iteration.

```
int Soupline::getSoup(int personID) {
   if (numBowlsSoupLeft <= 0) { // handles negative numBowlsSoupLeft
      return OUT_OF_SOUP;
   }
   bool found_customer = false;
   for (auto c : my_customers) {
      if (personID == c.person_id()) { // This is my guess on how the id is stored in customer class
         // Logic to process soup for customer
         found_customer = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (!found_customer) {
      // Logic to process non-customer asking for soup?
   }
}
```

Sorry i dunno what is the return integer is supposed to be, so it is not defined in my code example.

Comment: I tried that and got some weird errors so i changed the vector type to "customer" and most of the errors but one went away. The last remaining error says "error: no match for 'operator==' (operand command types are 'customer' and 'const int' " @michaelgbj

Comment: What is your my_customers? I thought it is a std::vector<int>
It looks like it is std::vector<Customer> instead? Then you would have to show what is the Customer class like and how you are comparing an integer (personID) to a Customer? Is there like a Customer.person_id or something?

Comment: you'd think there would be a "Customer" class wouldn't you. No I have no idea what the type "customer" is and there is nothing in any of the files that says it either. In this file I do have to make a "newCustomer" and call newCustomer.personID so I'm not sure, any thoughts?

Comment: Without knowing how the struct is defined, we are stuck. However, if you are expected to define the customer struct. that may be more straight-forward. You can even define the operator ==, so that you can use the find() function.

Comment: how would you define the "==" ??

Comment: those are more fundamental c++ concepts. Just google c++ operator overload.